# Update Panel in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm looking for a way to do a "Update Panel" in ASP.NET MVC 3. I found this link: [How to make update panel in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961612/how-to-make-update-panel-in-asp-net-mvc) but didn't work.

So, i did this in my view:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="userName" />
    <button type="button" onclick="searchUserByName()">Search</button>
</div>
<div id="usersPanel">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_UserList", Model);}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function searchUserByName() {
        var userName = $("#userName").val();

        $.post('@Url.Action("SearchUserByName")',
            {username: userName},
            function (htmlPartialView) {
                $("#usersPanel").html(htmlPartialView);
            }
        );
    }

</script>
```

And in my controller:

```
public ActionResult SearchUserByName(string userName)
{
    List<User> users = // code to search users by name

    return PartialView("_UserList", users);
}
```

But i don't know if is a good (or right) way to do that, or if there is a way to do this with asp.net mvc 3. There is a better way to do this, or with asp.net mvc 3?

Comment: I'd do it like that except I'd return JSON w/ the list items instead. Seems a little silly to re-add the all the users to the usersPanel every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use ajax request to get the results from your action methods. It basically does the same thing as update panels in asp.net.

So something like the following.

```
$.ajax({
async: false,
cache: false,
type: 'POST',
    url: /controller/action,
    data: { id: idParam },
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        if (confirmMessage !== undefined) {
            return confirm(confirmMessage);
        }
        return true;
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // do stuff
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('An error occured');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like that.

You might also want to take a look at client side libraries for handling bindings etc. Looks like [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) will be included in MVC4

Comment: To keep working with server side, i've to use jquery right? This lib is only to UI, in other words, i 'll get the result from $.post or $.ajax and set to view model defined with the knockoutjs? Because, if this works only with UI, so it doesn't address fully what i need, but looks like a great lib. Anyway, thak you!

Comment: yes. You'll still use jQuery to do ajax. But knockoutjs can bind the same information to multiple places on your page.

Answer (score 0):

In View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var userName = $("#userName").val();

 $.ajax({
            url: "/<ControolerName>/SearchUserByName",
            type: "POST",
            data: { userName: userName},
            success: function (result) {
                $('#divResults').html(result);
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert("Error");
            }

<script>
<div id="divResults">
</div>
```

In controller:

```
public PartialViewResult SearchUserByName(string userName)
{
     List<User> users = // code to search users by name

     return PartialView("_users", users);
}
```

Comment: Apart from rewriting the code given in the question, what is your answer here?