# Loading a section of a page dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out a way to load a section of my page dynamically with MVC. Currently I have a top menu, and side menu to the left that are shared layout. The main content is within the id "page-content-wrapper". The code looks as follows:

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Role";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="wrapper">

  @*Sidebar*@
  @Html.Partial("_Sidebar")


  @*PAGE CONTENT*@
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">

      <div>content</div>

  </div>@*page-content-wrapper*@
</div>@*wrapper End*@
```

In the page-content-wrapper section I'd like to switch between views, but not reload the entire page. Would AJAX panels be a good option? Or are there any online tutorials to assist me? Any options that will allow my page to run efficiently are welcomed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: there are many guides online, and many question answered on stackoverflow, here's one of 'em - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: [AJAX panels don't work in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961612/how-to-make-update-panel-in-asp-net-mvc), your thinking of webforms

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC is mostly a server-side front-end Web development tool. It won't assist you in your goal, also known as *single page application*.

Actually, you should leverage a HTML5/JavaScript solution to get an optimal result and move on, and today there're many *single page application* frameworks you can plug in your ASP.NET MVC application. For example, [AngularJS + UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).