# How to Consuming Duplex Service in MVC application and update it into View

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a WCF Duplex service, I would like to update to view, periodically, about a long running task. How could I do it with out redirect from the existing view.

Comment: Create an update panel type architecture then periodically fire the ajax which will update the partial view... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961612/how-to-make-update-panel-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thank you @PaulZahra , so don't we have any other way that can update from controller to view , with out a periodic check, like an event in WPF or winforms ?

Comment: I think that because the web page is entirely detached from the server you must have a period check in the the client somewhere... and a partial view will not refresh the whole page, just it's little bit. WPF and winforms are not entirely detached from it's 'view' making it possible to run via events, the only events in asp .net / MVC are to do with loading / unloading the view, sessions etc. There maybe some technology such as SQL Dependency which can run on an events basis, however I'm not aware of any other type of solution.

Comment: Ok @PaulZahra make sense, Thank you